# What is the maximum integer that can be saved in a LaTeX counter?

Tags: counters

I am using counters to save positive integers, something like that:

```
\setcounter{mycoutervalue}{59}
```

Is there any limit in the value I can save in a counter, in this case `mycountervalue`? And what is the exact limit?

Thanks!
I do not want to get an unexpected overflow.

Comment: I would say `2^31-1` with e-TeX extensions

Comment: Thaks for your quick answer!
Well, I am not using e-TeX extensions...

Comment: @loved.by.Jesus are you sure? That would be quite strange nowadays. A modern LaTeX kernel assumes etex available, many packages do as well.

Comment: @loved.by.Jesus: I confused the e-TeX extensions with the register range. The register range hasn't change, but the numbers of registers have increased.

Comment: @clemens: I had no idea what e-TeX was :-\, thanks for your explanation.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The maximum value is the 'usual' `2^31-1` long integer value, as well as the negative range from `-2^31`, so the full range is `2^32` integers possible.

`2^31-1` is 2147483647, which is the largest possible integer usable for counters or `\ifnum` and `\numexpr` codes.

In the code below I stored this number to the counter `\mycounter` and print it several times after using `\stepcounter`. After the first `\stepcounter` the register overflows and the number is set to `-2147483648`, being the 'largest' negative number possible. A subsequent `\stepcounter` works normally then.

The `e-TeX` standard extended the limit of 256 registers (count, skip etc.) to 32568 possible registers (for each type)

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcounter{mycounter}

\begin{document}

\setcounter{mycounter}{2147483647}

\themycounter  % prints 2147483647 

\stepcounter{mycounter}  % Now the overflow will occur

\themycounter % prints -2147483648

\stepcounter{mycounter}

\themycounter % -2147483647
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hey that is a nice coded answer! You got it.

Comment: @loved.by.Jesus: You're welcome

Answer (score 17):

According to The TEXbook:

> TEX has 256 registers called `\count0` to `\count255`, each capable of containing
>   integers between -2147483647 and +2147483647, inclusive; i.e., the magnitudes should be less than 2<sup>31</sup>.

Comment: A very minor detail: The minimal possible value of a counter is `-2147483648=-2^{31}`, not `-2147483647`. (There are `2^{32}` integers between `-2147483648` and `+2147483647`...)

Comment: @Mico does that mean The TeXBook has a typo?

Comment: @Symbol1 - Oh no, did I commit an act of heresy against the Book of K?!

Comment: I mean the other answer clearly shows that -21...48 is possible. So either TeXbook is wrong or the new compiler changed something.

Comment: @Symbol1 - Actually, there's no outright heresy. I wrote "The minimal possible value of a counter is -2147483648=-2^{31}, not -2147483647." However, while the minimal possible counter value, -2147483648, cannot be set directly, it can be reached by causing an overflow, as is demonstrated in the [other answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/270536/5001). For sure, the Book of K has it right when it is said that the counter's "magnitude" (a synonym for "absolute value"?) should be less than `2^{31}`. :-) Try running `\setcounter{mycounter}{-2147483648}` to verify that the Book of K is right.

Comment: @Symbol1 - Maybe it all comes down to an interpretation of what "capable of containing integers" means. I've never been good at exegesis, so I won't dare wade into these murky waters...

Comment: No problem. I wasn't good at making things precise either. I ran into this problem because apparently the range of dimensions is smaller, between ±2^30±1 sp; so I was searching for some authority.