# Integer and floating point accuracy in LaTeX3

Tags: expl3, l3fp

The L3fp package proposes the range of `randint` parameters to be `+- 10^16 - 1`; yet, I seem to be restricted to `+-2^31 - 1`, any value above it produces the `Number too big` compilation error. On the other hand I am getting the expected full 16-decimal digit accuracy for `fp` values. Why?

```
\documentclass{article}
% RN. 15 April 2017
% BRIEF DESCRIPTION:
%=======================
\usepackage[check-declarations]{expl3}
\usepackage{xparse}
%-----------------------
\ExplSyntaxOn
\int_new:N \l_rn_someInteger_int
\fp_new:N \l_rn_someFp_fp
\NewDocumentCommand\mySetInteger{m}
  {
    \int_set:Nn \l_rn_someInteger_int {#1}
    some~integer:~\int_use:N \l_rn_someInteger_int\\
    \int_set:Nn \l_rn_someInteger_int {\fp_eval:n {randint(#1)}}
    some~random~integer:~\int_use:N \l_rn_someInteger_int\\
    \fp_set:Nn \l_rn_someFp_fp {\fp_eval:n {rand()}}
    some~random~real:~\fp_use:N \l_rn_someFp_fp\\
    -------------------------------------------\\
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff
%-----------------------
\begin{document}
    \mySetInteger{1234}
    \mySetInteger{2147483647}

%   \mySetInteger{2147483648}
%   \mySetInteger{9999999999999999}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @Henri Menke et.al. The question as such was not what maximum integer can be stored in a LaTeX counter, but how to achieve the range `+- 10^16 - 1` as parameters for the `L3fp randint()` function, and that questions had been answered by @egreg: use the `xfp` package and operate with `fp` variables rather than with `int`s.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We can look at how `l3fp` stores a floating point expression:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xfp}

\begin{document}

\ttfamily

\ExplSyntaxOn % we want to do tests

\fp_set:Nn \l_tmpa_fp { randint(10^15,10^15+10^12) }

\fp_eval:n { \l_tmpa_fp }

\par

\cs_meaning:N \l_tmpa_fp

\ExplSyntaxOff

\end{document}
```

In one experiment, I get

[image]

that shows the random integer is not stored as an integer in TeX's original meaning, because the range is limited to the range –2<sup>31</sup> to 2<sup>31</sup>–1.

One simply can't assign an integer variable a value outside the above mentioned range.

Operating with “floating point integers” is subject to the standard limitations of floating point arithmetic, when operations are performed.

Similarly, after changing `randint` to `rand`, I got

[image]

The number is stored with the exponent and four groups of four digits for the significand. The two internal functions `\s__fp` and `\__fp_chk:w` are used for manipulating (expandably) the number. A terminator `;` ends the internal representation.

Comment: So, integers in the range `-2^15 ... +_2^15 - 1`, but package `xfp` allows me to work with `fp` variables that look like integers. I plugged your solution into my code and it does everything I need.

Comment: @ReinhardNeuwirth As long as you don't perform operations that overflow –10^16..10^16, you can trust those integers.

Answer (score 4):

The number `2147483648` is `2^31` exactly and `\int_...` variables are TeX count registers actually, which have a 'limited' number range, as have usual `LaTeX` counters, which is `- 2^{31} to 2^{31} - 1`, exactly `2^32` numbers.

If you look into the .log file of a file with expl3 loaded, you will see that the `\int...` macros are `\countXYZ` definitions actually.

Trying to store `2147483648` will generate an overflow as `\setcounter{foo}{2147483648}` would do as well.

Floating point numbers are stored differently as dimension registers and allow larger numbers, but the accuracy isn't better.

Please have a look on [What is the maximum integer that can be saved in a LaTeX counter?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/270535/what-is-the-maximum-integer-that-can-be-saved-in-a-latex-counter/270536#270536) as well.

Comment: would you agree though that package `xfp` does provide extended accuracy for `fp` numbers?

Comment: @ReinhardNeuwirth: No, not really. `xfp` is intented to be a wrapper for the `\fp_eval:n` features from `expl3` (or better: `l3fp`)