# How to calculate numbers bigger than 16383 in tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf, calculations, pgfmath

I was trying to output the positive integer powers of 2 starting from 2^10=1024. I was met with a `Dimension too large` error. When I force compiled, every number from 2^14=16384 was output as 16383. My guess is that 16384 is just beyond the default range of numbers covered by the engine and overflows raised an error. What can I do to enable computation of bigger numbers? In 2022 16383 is no where near enough.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \foreach \i in {10,...,20} {
        \node at (\i,0) {\pgfmathprint{int(2^\i)}};
    }
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: "In 2022 16383  is no where near enough" You are choosing to use a system whose arithmetic model has been unchanged since 1979 or so

Comment: (related question) If it were pgfplots in LuaLaTeX you have the option to use Lua → [pgfmath - pgfplots: Strange Bump in `\tanh` Function - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/611573/pgfplots-strange-bump-in-tanh-function/611646#611646)

Answer (score 10):

You could use the `bigintcalc` package (might take some time though for very large exponents).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{bigintcalc}
\begin{document}
\bigintcalcPow{2}{999}
\end{document}
```

produces:

[image]

(the number is a bit too big to fit the page...)

Answer (score 8):

Use a mathematical engine different from the `pgfmath` one, which is a fixed point system with the limits you discovered (BTW, it's [documented in the manual](https://tikz.dev/math-parsing)).

For example, you can use the LaTeX3 engine (floating point, IEEE 754, so you have to take into [account the accuracy](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/364787/38080)):

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xfp}% not needed in recent LaTeX, thanks @egreg!
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \foreach \i in {10,...,30} {
        \node at (0,0.5*\i) {\fpeval{2**\i}};
    }
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: One should note that for big numbers you get incorrect results due to the float-precision.

Comment: This is accurate up to `2^{53}`. With the most recent version of LaTeX (2022-06-01) you don't need to load `xfp`.

Comment: @egreg thanks for calculating it :)

Answer (score 7):

If you're free to use LuaLaTeX, the entire Lua math library is at your service.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\directlua{
```

```lua
  for i = 10,50 do
    tex.print ( i .. '\\ ' .. math.floor(2^i) .. '\\par')
  end
```

```tex
}
\end{document}
```

Because Lua treats `\` (backslash) as the main escape character, it's necessarty to input `\\` to force a single backslash character to be passed to LaTeX.

*Aside*: If the sole purpose of the exercise is to compute powers of 2, starting with `2^{10}`, the Lua code could be made a bit more efficient, by performing multiplication instead of exponentiation in each round of the `for` loop:

```lua
j = math.floor(2^9)  % initialize 'j' as 2^(10-1)
for i = 10,50 do
  j = 2*j
  tex.print ( i .. '\\ ' .. j .. '\\par')
end
```

---

The first fifteen rows of the resulting output are:

[image]

Answer (score 7):

There are macro packages which implement better arithmetic. For example `apnum.tex` implements arbitrary large numbers in arbitrary precision. This macro package is implemented using only classical TeX primitives. See `texdoc apnum`.

You can try:

```
\input apnum

\newcount\tmpnum \tmpnum=1
\def\A{2}
\loop
   \the\tmpnum: \A \par
   \ifnum\tmpnum<100 \advance\tmpnum by1 \evaldef\A{2*\A} \repeat
```

Comment: Why do you not use either `\apPOW` or `\evaldef\A{2^100}`?

Comment: (forget about my comment, forgot about the output bits)